# How to use a decorator to check arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have several functions that I want to give default arguments.  Since these defaults should be newly-initialized objects, I can't just set them as defaults in the argument list.  It introduces a lot of clunky code to default them to None and check in every single function

```
def FunctionWithDefaults(foo=None):
  if foo is None:
    foo = MakeNewObject()
```

To reduce repeated code, I made a decorator to initialize parameters.

```
@InitializeDefaults(MakeNewObject, 'foo')
def FunctionWithDefaults(foo=None):
  # If foo wasn't passed in, it will now be equal to MakeNewObject()
```

The decorator I wrote is as such:

```
def InitializeDefaults(initializer, *parameters_to_initialize):
  """Returns a decorator that will initialize parameters that are uninitialized.

  Args:
    initializer: a function that will be called with no arguments to generate
        the values for the parameters that need to be initialized.
    *parameters_to_initialize: Each arg is the name of a parameter that
        represents a user key.
  """
  def Decorator(func):
    def _InitializeDefaults(*args, **kwargs):
      # This gets a list of the names of the variables in func.  So, if the
      # function being decorated takes two arguments, foo and bar,
      # func_arg_names will be ['foo', 'bar'].  This way, we can tell whether or
      # not a parameter was passed in a positional argument.
      func_arg_names = inspect.getargspec(func).args
      num_args = len(args)
      for parameter in parameters_to_initialize:
        # Don't set the default if parameter was passed as a positional arg.
        if num_args <= func_arg_names.index(parameter):
          # Don't set the default if parameter was passed as a keyword arg.
          if parameter not in kwargs or kwargs[parameter] is None:
            kwargs[parameter] = initializer()
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _InitializeDefaults
  return Decorator
```

That works great if I only need to decorate it once, but it breaks with multiple decorations.  Specifically, suppose I want to initialize foo and bar to separate variables:

```
@InitializeDefaults(MakeNewObject, 'foo')
@InitializeDefaults(MakeOtherObject, 'bar')
def FunctionWithDefaults(foo=None, bar=None):
  # foo should be MakeNewObject() and bar should be MakeOtherObject()
```

That breaks because in the second decorator, func_arg_defaults gets the arguments of the first decorator rather than FunctionWithDefaults.  As a result, I can't tell whether or not a parameter has already been passed in positionally.

Is there any clean way to solve this problem?

Things that don't work:

- functools.wraps(func) makes the `__name__` of the function the decorated function, but it doesn't change the arguments (unless there's a different way to do it).
- inspect.getcallargs doesn't raise an exception in the second decorator
- using func.func_code.co_varnames doesn't provide the function's arguments in the second decorator

I could just use one decorator, but that seems less clean, and it feels like there should be a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the best advice you'd get about decorators in python: use [`wrapt.decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt).

It would make the task of writing decorators much simpler (you don't need to write a function inside a function inside a function), and would avoid all the errors which everybody makes when writing even simple decorators. To learn what those are, you might want to read Graham Dumpleton's [blog posts](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/how-you-implemented-your-python.html) titled "How you implemented your Python decorator is wrong" (he is very convincing)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a variable to the wrapper function containing the argspec (e.g. `__argspec`):

```
def Decorator(func):

    # Retrieve the original argspec
    func_arg_names = getattr(func, '__argspec', inspect.getargspec(func).args)

    def _InitializeDefaults(*args, **kwargs):
        # yada yada

    # Expose the argspec for wrapping decorators
    _InitializeDefaults.__argspec = func_arg_names

    return _InitializeDefaults
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your decorator to accept a dictionary of arguments and the default value that you want? I don't see why it would be less cleaner than multiple decorations with different arguments. Here is a sample that works fine for me. I made minor changes to your code to reflect dictionary as an argument:
    import inspect

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Personality'


class Human(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Human'


class Animal(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Animal'

#def InitializeDefaults(**initializerDict):
def InitializeDefaults(**initializerDict):
    """Returns a decorator that will initialize parameters that are uninitialized.

    Args:
      initializer: a function that will be called with no arguments to generate
          the values for the parameters that need to be initialized.
      *parameters_to_initialize: Each arg is the name of a parameter that
          represents a user key.
    """

    def Decorator(func):
        def _InitializeDefaults(*args, **kwargs):
            # This gets a list of the names of the variables in func.  So, if the
            # function being decorated takes two arguments, foo and bar,
            # func_arg_names will be ['foo', 'bar'].  This way, we can tell whether or
            # not a parameter was passed in a positional argument.
            func_arg_names = inspect.getargspec(func).args
            num_args = len(args)
            for parameter in initializerDict:
                # Don't set the default if parameter was passed as a positional arg.
                if num_args <= func_arg_names.index(parameter):
                    # Don't set the default if parameter was passed as a keyword arg.
                    if parameter not in kwargs or kwargs[parameter] is None:
                        kwargs[parameter] = initializerDict[parameter]()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _InitializeDefaults
    return Decorator


#@InitializeDefaults(Human, 'foo')

@InitializeDefaults(foo = Human, bar = Animal)
def FunctionWithDefaults(foo=None, bar=None):
    print foo.name
    print bar.name


#test by calling with no arguments
FunctionWithDefaults()

#program output
Human
Animal
```